# Игра 'Snake' . Как отобразить тело змейки с > 1 символ

Tags: python, pygame

```
class Snake:
    def __init__(self, symbol='o', position=(1, 1)):
      self.symbol = symbol
      self.body = [position]
```

Эта функция создает Snake с одним символом

```
def render(self):
    i, j = self.snake.body[0]
    self.board.board[i][j] = self.snake.symbol
```

Какой надо создать цикл. для того что бы добавить n символов к телу Змеи?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! В этом сообществе все вопросы / ответы / комментарии обязаны быть **на русском** языке, исправьте своё сообщение заменив текст на русский. Вопрос можно отредактировать кнопкой «[edit]».

Comment: Проголосовал за переоткрытие вопроса :) Нужно хранить список координат тела змеи. Рисовать, проходя по циклу из координат. Перемещать змею, вставляя первым элементом новую позицию головы, удаляя последний элемент. При поедании добавлять текущую координату в список. Пример: https://github.com/gil9red/snake/blob/5c57b9701f3a34c6b8947fd1a412e85653e963b9/snake.py#L73-L74